# attaching maps in CW complexes

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, cw-complexes

Suppose I have a finite CW complex $X$ with $p$-skeleton $X^{(p)}$.

- Let $\varphi_f \colon S^p \to X^{(p)}$ be part of the attaching map of a $(p+1)$-cell $f$.
- Let $\Phi_e \colon D^p \to X^{(p)}$ be part of the attaching map of a $p$-cell $e$ and let $q_e \colon X^{(p)} \to S^p$ be the map that collapses everything outside of $\Phi_e(Int(D^p)) \subset X^{(p)}$ to a point.

Suppose that the map $\theta = q_e \circ \varphi_f \colon S^p \to X^{(p)} \to S^p$ is surjective. Let $x_0  = \Phi_e(0) \in X^{(p)}$.

> Is it possible to change $\varphi_f$ by a homotopy to a map $\hat{\varphi}_f$, such that $\hat{\varphi}_f^{-1}(x_0)$ is a finite set of points?

Since $\theta$ is a continuous map between smooth manifolds, it is homotopic to a smooth map. Hence, I can arrange that $\theta^{-1}(x_0)$ is a finite set of points after a homotopy. But the result of the homotopy may not lift to a map $S^p \to X^{(p)}$.

I tried to change $\varphi_f$ only inside the preimage of the open cell in $X^{(p)}$ and keep the rest fixed, but I did not manage to ensure that there are no new points created in the process that are mapped to $x_0$.

Comment: Let me suggest that you transfer this question over to math.stackexchange, which is a more appropriate venue for it.

Comment: @LeeMosher Well, I would, but I don't have a math.stackexchange account and will not create one only for this question. Feel free to close it if you find it too trivial, but I couldn't find anything in the literature that was helpful. It could very well be that I am overlooking something very trivial here and I would be thankful for a hint. At least I can assure you that this is not a homework problem :-).

Comment: The short answer is, changing the attaching map by a homotopy does not affect the homotopy type of the CW complex. And so if you have to change it then you have to change it.

Comment: I think you don't actually need to do much to create a math.stackexchange, account since MO has migrated to 2.0 everything is part of the SE network and it would be associated with this account automatically. Not that this is an argument for you to migrate or get an MSE account.

Comment: @LeeMosher Sorry for being utterly incompetent here, but I fail to see how that answers the question, which is not about the homotopy type of $X$. The question is: Is it possible to change the attaching map locally to have the stated form of regularity.

Comment: If someone needs a motivation for this: My original problem is related to cellular versions of twisted generalised cohomology theories and involves expressing the degree of the map $\theta$ via local degrees, which should be possible if I can find at least one regular value of the form stated in the question.

Comment: I don't see why questions that are easy for specialists necessarily belong on MSE. (Sorry to keep banging the same drum.) Also, some of us have sworn off MSE...

Comment: I am a little bit confused. SInce you are supposing that $\theta$ is well-defined, you are also supposing that $\phi _f$ is injective?  If this is the case, then the answer is trivial...

Comment: @user43326 You do not need $\varphi_f$ to be injective to have a well-defined map $\theta$. The only injective map is $\Phi_e$ restricted to the interior of the disk, since it is an attaching map.

Comment: @user43326 If you look up cellular homology, the map $\theta$ is the one, whose degree gives the matrix entry at position $(e,f)$ in the differential of the cellular chain complex.

Comment: I think, I got it. Anyway, thanks for listening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is essentially Lemma 4.10 of Hatcher's book, which is the key step in proving the cellular approximation theorem. It shows that you can homotope $\varphi_f$ so that there is an open set $U$ in your $p$-cell $e$ such that $\varphi_f$ is piecewise linear on the inverse image of $U$. Then a general element of $U$ has only finitely many preimages.

Comment: Thank you, Dan! I think I found a solution in the smooth setting as well. One just has to be a little more careful using the Whitney approximation theorem.

Comment: That sounds right - cellular approximation can also be proved using Whitney approximation + Sard's theorem.